# STM32F407VG Discovery Board, on board ST Link not recognized, but the pc recognized J Link is connected

Tags: arduino, stm32, st-link, j-link

So I have a STM32F407VG Discovery Board, the board has ST Link. But when I connect the usb to my pc, the ide that I used does not recognized it. I used atollic and stm32cube ide. But when I check my device manager, there is a device connected named j-link and it said it is working fine. I don't really know what to do.

[image]

Comment: did you confirm the stlink/debug firmware is up to date (there is a firmware update tool on the st site)

Comment: I think so, I install STSW-LINK009 driver from the ST website. Then I tried STSW-LINK007
to upgrade the firmware but it also does not detect the on board st link

Comment: IMO there is a hack to make a J-link from onboard ST-link, so probably your device was hacked, you have to find the possibility to roll back. https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/

Comment: Yeah, there is that possibility, because it is used microcontroller from the robotics club in university. I will tried to roll it back.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoBuršič , for the solution you give works and now I can use the onboard ST-Link.

Comment: Regarding "close" votes, while this question does look like off-topic, it is certainly useful to people visiting this site. I, for one, had no idea that on-board STM programmer can be turned into J-link and that the process is reversible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Maple I deleted the answer. And For  
@MarkoBuršič your solution works, and can you please add the solution to the answer.

Comment: @LazyEmperor Done.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option from Segger to convert an on-board ST-Link to a J-link. Your device was probably yet converted, so you have to find the possibility to roll back.

https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/